# How to tell a Grails plugin to use a secondary datasource (not the default one)?

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, grails-2.0

I have created a plugin that is responsible for RDBMS access to a secondary datasource this way we hide the domain and service layer from the application that is going to use it (it impedes them from modifying that source). I have the plugn published to artifactory and then imported it successfully into my  application. However, the datasource file that the plugin uses got excluded from packaging and when calling the service methods in the plugin it's trying to execute those queries against my default datasource.

1. Is there a way to tell the grails plugin to not use the default datasource but a secondary datasource? or is there a way to have the plugin not exclude its own DataSource.groovy file?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

The answer provided below would work, basically that is how multiple data sources work in Grails. The only drawback to that is that when I am developing the plugin itself and I want to run it as an app to make sure it does what I want the datasource that grails expects must be called **dataSource** so I have to comment out the

```
static mapping = {
  // datasource 'dataSource_lookup'
}
```

in order to be able to run it. Then when i see that every thing is good as I desire and I want to publish the plugin I have to go trhough all of my domain files and uncomment the line above so that when the plugin is imported into my main app it will have  a reference to the secondary data source. However, this is very very painful and slow.

Is there a better way to do this? Why does the default datasource have to be called **dataSource**? can that be changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Domain Classes of your plugin you have to do something like this

```
static mapping ={
    //if you need to use the second ds only in Production you can use the Environment
    if(Environment.PRODUCTION){
        datasource('your_sencondary_datasource')
    }
}
```

and in your principal application in your Datasource.groovy you need to map your datasource like this

```
production{
    dataSource {
        <'your configs of primary ds'>
    }

    dataSource_you_secondary_datasource {
        <'your configs to secondary ds'>
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also inject the secondary datasource into grails services:

    def dataSource_your_secondary_datasource

Comment: I understand that this solution will work but that means that all my domains have to have the static mapping entry indicating the name of the datasourse to use. The problem now is that when I am developing the plugin itself I have to comment out the mapping from all of the domains because when I run the plugin individually it expects the data source  to be called datasource instead of datasource_lookup. This makes it very improductive every time i want to develop the plugin commenting out and each time im ready to release uncomment and then publish the plugin. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: @meurer forgot to mention you in my comment, please see above see if you have any suggestions.

Comment: @Viriato, i don't know if this is the best way to solve this problem, but you can use the Environment.PRODUCTION in your domain class. Something like this, if(Environment.PRODUCTION){ datarouce('your_ds')}

Comment: @meurer thanks for updating your answer that totally did it. I knew about Environment, I have used it in Bootstrap in the past as well. Not sure why I did not think of it.